# Intercept activemq devices ids

Tags: activemq-classic, mqtt

When broker has one publisher and subscriber (via MQTT) there are no messages in persistance. I tested in LevelDB and MySQL. In LevelDB was only topics name. Maybe configuration was wrong or I need another persistance? Maybe MQTT messages not writes to message storage?

My task is **get publishe/subscriber id's**. How can I do this, maybe some of this:

- get another persistance, such KahaDB with archiveDataLogs=true or high performance journal?
- configured 'correctly' persistance?
- get some logs or journal of broker?
- write plug-in and get this data from RAM?

Version 5.9.

LevelDb configurtion:

```
 <persistenceAdapter>
  <LevelDB directory="${activemq.data}/leveldb"/>
 </persistenceAdapter>
```

Now, I tried to get log archive in KahaDB? but no result. Archive folder empty:

```
<persistenceAdapter>
  <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb" archiveDataLogs="true" directoryArchive="${activemq.data}/datalog"/>
 </persistenceAdapter>
```

Thanks.

Comment: please post the version you are using and some configuration or code with your question or no one is going to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in ActiveMQ but I think this could be pretty hard to achieve. Is using ActiveMQ a hard requirement for you or can you change the product?

If ActiveMQ isn't a hard reuqirement, an alternative might be to use a full-featured MQTT broker which explicitly allows to do message interception such as [HiveMQ](http://www.hivemq.com). With the plugin system it's perfectly possible to intercept messages, extract things and save it to a database of choice (be it SQL or NoSQL). You can find a blog post with a big picture how this would work [here](http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-sql-database/).

The documentation for the plugin system can be found [here](http://www.hivemq.com/docs/plugins/latest/).

Please note that I may be biased since I work on HiveMQ.

Comment: ActiveMQ is good because it support multiply [protocols](http://activemq.apache.org/protocols.html). Task was changed. I need only publishe/subscriber id's, not messages.